# How to create conditional joins in HQL to workaround UNION

Tags: hibernate, hql, union

I actually need to translate a `UNION` query to `CASE..WHEN` as `UNION` is not supported in `HQL`. The actual query looks like -

```
select * from table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.a_version=table2.id  --deciding JOIN
JOIN table3 ON table2.t2id=table3.id
JOIN table4 ON table3.t2id=table4.id
WHERE table2.col3='abc'
UNION
select * from table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.b_version=table2.id  --deciding JOIN
UNION
select * from table1 
JOIN table2 ON table1.c_version=table2.id  --deciding JOIN
```

The first `JOIN` is the deciding one, if further JOIN should be made or not.
I do not want to be making native SQL queries. Can I have a `CASE.. WHEN` here to avoid the `UNION` ?

Or can I do it as below ?

```
select * from table1 
JOIN table2 ON ((table1.a_version=table2.id AND table2.col3='abc') 
               OR table1.b_version=table2.id 
               OR table1.b_version=table2.id)
JOIN table3 ON (table2.t2id=table3.id AND table1.a_version=table2.id)
JOIN table4 ON (table3.t2id=table4.id AND table1.a_version=table2.id)
```

Comment: maybe OR table1.b_version=table2.id is OR table1.c_version=table2.id

Comment: You can run 3 different query and then merge the data in the list